# Adding parameters to the relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a query the uses many `->with()` in Laravel like so:

```
$campaign = $this->campaign
        ->with('tracks.flights.asset')->take(4)
        ->with('tracks.group')
        ->with('tracks.media')
        ->with('tracks.flights.comments')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->find($id);
```

and in the `Track` model i have this method:

```
public function flights()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Flight\Flight')->orderBy('start_date');
}
```

What I want to achieve is having the same result as now but i want to put date constrains on the flight level, for example something like this:

```
public function flights($start_date, $end_date) //dynamic dates
{
    return $this->hasMany('Flight\Flight')->whereRaw('start_date > $start_date and end_date < $end_date')->orderBy('start_date');
}
```

How can I achieve this kind of result? I am fairly new to Laravel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Chain a `whereHas` onto your query.

```
$campaign = $this->campaign
    ->with('tracks.flights.asset')->take(4)
    ->with('tracks.group')
    ->with('tracks.media')
    ->with('tracks.flights.comments')
    ->whereHas('tracks.flights', function($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
        $q->where('start_date',  '>', $start_date)->where('end_date', '<', $end_date)->orderBy('start_date');
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->find($id);
```

Keep in mind the `orderBy` will only order the results returned within the flights relation, not the campaigns themselves.

Comment: I am receiving this error now: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::flights(). Maybe i should do tracks.flights in the whereHas condition?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry.  It should be `tracks.flights`

Comment: Nope, same error, I tweaked my original one and in my response below is how i actually solved it.

Comment: I just realized in your question, you wanted to put a constraint on the flights themselves, not constrain the the campaigns based on the flights so your solution would be the better one.

Comment: Yes, but your solution pointed me in the right direction. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i came up with after reading Eloquent ORM in Laravel

```
        $campaign = $this->campaign
        ->with(array('tracks.flights' => function($query)
            {
                $query->whereRaw('flights.start_date > "2016-01-09 00:00" AND flights.end_date < "2016-01-16 00:00"')
                ->with('asset')->take(4)
                ->with('comments');
            }
        ))
        ->with('tracks.group')
        ->with('tracks.media')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->find($id);
```